# Who are the characters in this Top Gear episode supposed to be?

Tags: story-identification, tv, character-identification

I was watching an episode of Top Gear (series 2, episode 8) and they said "Have you ever wondered who is the fastest Master of the Universe in a Honda?"

[image: Photo of 5 cosplayers on tarmac at a fenced-off facility of some sort. From left to right are Darth Vader; a silver suit with a silver mask with a stylized frowning mouth, round eyes and bulky ear covers connected over the top of the head like headphones; a bald man in a blue robe with a white cape and a head-high, stiff, circular flaring collar; a Next-Generation-era Klingon; and a black pepper pot with silver studs and plungers sticking out in place of arms.]

Darth Vader and the Klingon are obvious, but I have no idea what the other three are supposed to represent, or why they would be considered Masters of the Universe.

Comment: As far as I'm conscerned, there is only one MOTU (hint: I don't mean she-ra)

Comment: Now I've got to find that episode. I'm guessing the Dalek didn't do well, not having the appendages to control a Honda well.

Comment: How do you not recognise the Dalek?!

Answer (score 33, accepted):

L to R: Vader, [Cyberman](http://tardis.wikia.com/wiki/Cyberman), [Ming the Merciless](http://www.imdb.com/character/ch0014683/), Klingon, [Dalek](http://tardis.wikia.com/wiki/Dalek).

**Darth Vader**: Sith Lord, sometime Jedi, master of the Force, and protagonist/antagonist of the Star Wars saga.
**Cybermen**: A master race of emotionless, superior, cybernetically augmented humanoids from the Doctor Who series.
**Ming the Merciless**: Despotic ruler of the planet Mongo and archenemy of Flash Gordon.
**Klingons**: A species of honorable warriors from the planet Qo'noS in the Star Trek universe.
**Daleks**: Genetically engineered aliens (biological creatures integrated within impregnable robotic tanks), with advanced technology and a relentless drive for universal domination; greatest enemies of the Doctor.

Answer (score 13):

From left to right, the other three are a Cyberman (from Doctor Who), Ming the Merciless (from Flash Gordon), and a Dalek (from Doctor Who).

Comment: Missed it by one minute and only 1/3 the votes. :(